# web app : sharing settings

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an apps script, a web app (within google site, share option: "Who has access to the app:anyone within mydomain" when publishing it) who make a forms using code as :

```
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
```

.....

When user press submit button the data are saved in a spreadsheet.

I have to give full access to an user group on this spreadsheet in order to make the forms works.

the problem, is that i don't want user1 (belonging to the user group) see what user2(belonging to the user group) has save in this spreadsheet.

At the moment, i share the spreadsheet without notifications but users are style able to access the spreadsheet using "shared with me" button on the drive.

Question: 
Is that possible to hide share (like $ share on windows)?

Is that possible to let the script special grant option to read/write the spreadsheet without sharing it with the user group on run time.

or how the actual google forms (the one provide by google drive, not mine) handle this problem ?

Google API is not activate in my domain, i have a google education license and i am the admin of this domain.

hope it's clear enough.^^

thanks for hwelp

Answer (score 0):

Your spreadsheet must be shared as 'anyone with the link can EDIT', as long as you don't publish this link no one will be able to find it and it will not appear in their 'shared with me' category.

Your webapp however will allow each user to fill the spreadsheet with their date by using the form.

see [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907321/session-getactiveuser-getemail-workaround-for-distributing-grades-from-a-spr) that shows a practical example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Forms, you do not need to share your spreadsheet at all. You can distribute the URL for the live form, and from there users can only enter form data. Forms are static, though - you can edit the questions easily, and create logical flows between pages of questions based on previous answers, but you cannot dynamically include data. You're also very limited in your options for layout. But aside from that, the ease of use and information security make them a good option.

With Legacy Forms, collected data is stored in a spreadsheet. Since the introduction of the new Forms, you need to first create your spreadsheet, then select Forms - Create Legacy Form to start. The "Summary of Responses" report reflects what is in the form table in the spreadsheet. Any changes you make to the sheet affect this, for example row deletion, addition, or information edits.

With the new Forms, introduced in February 2013, the collected data is attached to the Form, not a Spreadsheet. You can choose to have it copied to a spreadsheet, but since that is a copy, any edits you make to it will not be reflected in the "Summary of Responses". You can create a new Form from the "Create" dialog in Drive, or from within a spreadsheet.

Comment: the post author is using an UiApp designed form , not a Google form so the spreadsheet sharing parameters are relevant.

Comment: They did ask how Forms handles this situation. Even if they didn't ask, I'd have suggested it, because it appears that the only reason that access to the spreadsheet is required is to allow the UiApp to write to it when running as the end-user. Since even "shared by link" docs can show up in search results (if linked by another doc, including the UiApp), hiding it does not actually protect it.

Comment: @Modsgad your info was pertinent... just one point : the spreadsheet does not appear to the end user when shared by the link, You can [test it here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzdtAVonM1STL9Z46mtx5F79gkicy933OHlgfh2YsiQLPf-MrY/exec), the spreadsheet is called 'test shared' (without quotes) and I doubt you can find it in your docs.

Comment: It won't show up in Drive as a shared doc. But read the [Document Sharing Options](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60781), about "People at this organization with the link", "...documents with this visibility won’t normally be found in search results, except possibly if a document is linked to from within another searchable document." In this case, the sheet may be linked from a UiApp, depending on how it's coded, and if the UiApp is searchable, the link will be followed. Internal google searches could show it. I've stated it as a possibility, something to be aware of.

Comment: @Sergeinsas... take a look at cell F3 in your spreadsheet. It took me seconds to get there from the UiApp, and edit content in the sheet. The link to the spreadsheet is open in the UiApp, and WILL be followed by search engines.

Comment: Ok, You convinced me !! ;-) that's not good news :-// but thanks a lot for pointing that out.